# Create "underline to circle" animation while scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, svg

i tried to create an animation like this:

[image]

You can see the 3 steps, i want to **animate them while scrolling** - so the line under the headline should move to the hamburger an create a circle.

**GIF example**: https://dribbble.com/shots/1746065-Floating-burger-2-0

I created a headline which is scrolling with the text and an div at `position:absolute;` for the hamburger:

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/zzcjtx5a/

Also found a **similar animation**: http://codepen.io/sreucherand/pen/gHDaI
But to be honest i dont know how i should start.

Is this even possible?

---

**Final result**: http://jsfiddle.net/eegrsdxc/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats Weird! 
Found that today when login to my pen:

[The Exact same Animation - click to see!](http://codepen.io/shlomohass/pen/BDIsd)

```
<div class="content">

    <h2>Scroll to see the magic.</h2>

    <div class="header__fake">

        <div class="icn__wrap">
            <i class="icn__hamburger"></i>
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="58px" height="58px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="6.215" transform="rotate(90 8 8)"></circle>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <i class="btm__border"></i>

    </div>


    <h1>Tah-da!<span>Now scroll back up.</span></h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that your best bet is to have two animations.

1. a horizonal line that disappears completely in the end
2. a circle that appears from nothing

In both cases you can manipulate the stroke-dasharray property to animate the line from completely stroked to completely invisible.

Note that the origin of a circle is the rightmost point by default so it would make life easier for you if you appled a rotate transform to the circle so that it's start/end was at the bottom.